# JavaScript: Injecting CSS code using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parsing

So, I've just started developing a twitch event list with Streamlabs' kinda API and probably got some trouble accessing the style trough jQuery. What I am trying to accomplish is creating `.widget-EventList li:nth-child`-s depending on the value of `{max__events}` and besides, reduce the amount of opacity. Sure, I could add those classes manually to the CSS, and I did first, but there was missing a lot of dynamic and user-friendliness. There are two functions I can write code in:

That's the problematic function, it's called on widget load:

```
document.addEventListener('onLoad', function(obj) {

            $('.widget-EventList .message').css("background", "black"); // experimental, doesn't work either, tho

            var opMax = 1 / {max__events}; 
            for(var i = {max__events}; i <= 1; i++){ 
              let temp1 = 1 - opMax;
              $('.widget-EventList li:nth-child(' + i + ') div:last-child {}').insertAfter('.widget-EventList .message');
              $('.widget-EventList li:nth-child(' + i + ') div:last-child').css("color", "{font_color}");
              $('.widget-EventList li:nth-child(' + i + ') div:last-child').css("opacity", temp1);
              opMax++;
            }    
        });
```

Here's the additional function I can write into, it's called on widget event receive:

```
document.addEventListener('onEventReceived', function(obj) {

             $('.widget-EventList .message').css("background", "black"); // experimental, and works perfectly fine

       });
```

That's the position it is supposed to be in:

```css
.widget-EventList .message {
  float: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin: 4.5 0.25em;
  display: inline-block;
}


/*style list-elements <<-----HERE----- */
```

Maybe `document.addEventListener('onLoad', function(obj))` is loading way before the css even got loaded? What am I missing here?

Comment: Event names don't have `on` at the beginning, and they're lowercase. It should be `addEventListener("load", ...)`

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, why don't you use `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Intermixing jQuery and vanilla javascript operations is a code smell to begin with.  If you're already taking the hit for loading jQuery, you might as well use it, unless you have a legitimate reason not to

Comment: Don't use JS to amend the actual content in a stylesheet. It makes far more sense to temporarily apply a class to the element, or use `transition` or `animation` if you want to highlight something for a short period

Comment: @Barmar , `$( document ).ready()` is a nice objection; I'll consider that! Referring to your first comment, it was pre-set with the beginning, so I didn't question it.

Comment: Are the listener functions running? I don't think they should be with these errors. Did you try setting breakpoints or putting `console.log` statements to verify? What debugging have you done before posting here?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , hm... I get your point. I'll reconsider that!

Comment: @Barmar , that's what I forgot to mention! Since it's integrated in Streamlabs, I have no such an option to access debugging functions, unlikely. In terms of I am not missing something, anyway. I already tried `console.log`, though, it's not working.

Comment: @Barmar , after adding `$( document ).ready()` as you suggested me, the background I fired up experimentally started working; other than the loop.